# How do I get my code to close the dropdown menu when the user clicks "Category" while it's already opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/83vtn5h7/

Click 'Category' to open the menu. Now, if you click 'Category' again, the expected result would be for the menu to close. Instead, it closes but then quickly opens again! I can't find in my code what's causing this error. Please assist.

I thought having "slideToggle" on ActiveListItem (ActiveListItem = "Category" unless another item is chosen) would be the correct code, but it's not working.

HTML

```
        <div id="navbarcontainer">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li>
                    <span class="ActiveListItem">Category</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Music</span></li>
                        <li><span>Movie</span></li>
                        <li><span>Book</span></li>
                        <li><span>TV</span></li>
                        <li><span>Game</span></li>
                        <li><span>Activity</span></li>
                        <li><span>Misc</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#navbarcontainer{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;   
}


/* navbar */


ul.navbar {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#739FE0;
    width:100px;                
    border-radius:4px;
    height:33px;
}


ul.navbar li span.ActiveListItem {
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/p0qeihf.png") !important; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-size:10px 10px !important;
    background-position:83px 13px !important;
    color:white; !important;
    background-color:#222 !important;
    padding:7.5px 0px !important; 
    font-weight:normal !important;
    border-radius:4px;
    height:18px;
    width:100px;   
    margin-bottom:1px;
}


ul.navbar li {    
    z-index:101;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;                        
}


ul.navbar li span {
        display:block;
        color:white;
        padding:10px 5px;
        text-decoration:none;
        transition:all .1s ease-in;
}


ul.navbar li span:hover,
ul.navbar li:hover > span {
    background:#739FE0;
    color:#FFFFFF;  
    cursor:pointer;
}


ul.navbar li ul {
    margin-top:0px;               
    background:#222;
    display:none;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
                    0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}


ol, ul { list-style:outside none none; }
```

jQuery

```
var container = $('.navbar');
$(document).on('click', '.ActiveListItem', function(event) {
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(300);
    $('.navbar > li:first-child > span').text("Category");
});

$(document).on('click', '.navbar ul span', function(event) {   
    $("#input1").focus();
    $('.navbar li ul').slideUp(300);
    $('.navbar > li:first-child > span').text($(this).text());
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('.navbar li ul').slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `stop()` before the toogle event :

```
$(document).on('click', '.ActiveListItem', function(event) {
    $('.navbar li ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
    $('.navbar > li:first-child > span').text("Category");
});
```

Please find the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/83vtn5h7/1/) update

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Looks like I have some new stuff to learn about. =)

Comment: Delight to have helped :)